# Regex to validate at least two character classes (letters, number , special characters)

Tags: java, regex

I want to match at least two character classes in java for a input string that contains only small letters[a-z], capital letters[A-Z], numbers[0-9], special characters [!#+,-./:=@] .

I have arrived at the below mentioned regex but it's not working :

```
((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\\d]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\d]))|((?=.*[!#+,.\\=:=@-])(?=.*[\\d]))|((?=.*[!#+,.\\=:=@-])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[!#+,.\\=:=@-])(?=.*[A-Z]))
```

Examples :

```
wel123 - valid
123@@! - valid
@@@aaa - valid
!!!BDC - valid
ABC123 - valid
rrirrra - invalid
1234567 - invalid
ABCFESS - invalid
@@@!!!! - invalid
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you do this with multiple regexes?

Comment: Please provide example input strings for a case that should succeed and a case that should not.

Comment: Please provide a sample string and desired output.

Comment: Can you share your current code and tell exactly what is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing missing in your regex is adding start `^` and `$` end anchors and grouping whole of your regex properly. I've also removed unnecessary grouping from your regex and you can use this regex,

```
^(?:(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\d])|(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d])|(?=.*[!#+,.\\=:=@-])(?=.*[\d])|(?=.*[!#+,.\\=:=@-])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[!#+,.\\=:=@-])(?=.*[A-Z])).+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mqI2sg/1)**

Although this approach works but I'll suggest you to write a code for achieving this, as this regex may not be maintainable for people in general.

**Java Code approach to validate strings rather than pure big regex**

Following is an approach using Java codes, where you can pass a `List` of patterns to a method, along with the string to be validated and a number which is the minimum patterns required to match. Check this code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int minRequiredMatch = 2;
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("wel123","123@@!","@@@aaa","!!!BDC","ABC123","rrirrra","1234567","ABCFESS","@@@!!!!");

    list.forEach(x -> {
        System.out.println(x + " - " + (validateTwoCharSets(x, minRequiredMatch)?"Valid":"Invalid"));
    });
}

public static boolean validateTwoCharSets(String str, int minRequiredMatch) {
    List<Pattern> patList = new ArrayList<>();
    patList.add(Pattern.compile("[a-z]"));
    patList.add(Pattern.compile("[A-Z]"));
    patList.add(Pattern.compile("[0-9]"));
    patList.add(Pattern.compile("[!#+,-./:=@]"));

    return validateTwoCharSets(patList, str, minRequiredMatch);
}

public static boolean validateTwoCharSets(List<Pattern> patList, String str, int minRequiredMatch) {
    if (minRequiredMatch <0 || minRequiredMatch > patList.size()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("minRequiredMatch must be a positive number and not more than pattern list size.");
    }
    int matchCount = 0;

    for (Pattern p : patList) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        if (m.find()) {
            matchCount++;
        }
        if (matchCount >= minRequiredMatch) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

For your given data set prints following,

```
wel123 - Valid
123@@! - Valid
@@@aaa - Valid
!!!BDC - Valid
ABC123 - Valid
rrirrra - Invalid
1234567 - Invalid
ABCFESS - Invalid
@@@!!!! - Invalid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pushpesh for the regex as well as clean java approach.

Comment: Glad to help @MohitAgrawal. Also, I'll suggest you to go with Java code approach as you can see it is very flexible and maintainable way. Say tomorrow you decide, that instead of any two patterns, any three patterns should match, then instead of dealing with that massive regex change, all you need to do is just change that value you need to pass as argument from 2 to 3. Should be cake walk using Java code.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want a regex that matches any string that contains at least 2 *consecutive* characters from the set you defined.

I'd go with this :

```
.*[\w\d!#+,-./:=@]{2}.*
```

See full code :

```java
package so20190502;

public class TwoOrMoreChars {

    public TwoOrMoreChars() {
    }

    public boolean matches(String s) {
        return s.matches(".*[\\w\\d!#+,-./:=@]{2}.*");
    }

    private void testString(String s) {
        System.out.println("String '" + s + "' does " + (matches(s)?"":"NOT") + " match.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwoOrMoreChars me = new TwoOrMoreChars();
        me.testString("1");
        me.testString("1%2");
        me.testString("1%2%a%-%'");
        me.testString("1%2a-'");
    }

}
```

This outputs :

```
String '1' does NOT match.
String '1%2' does NOT match.
String '1%2%a%-%'' does NOT match.
String '1%2a-'' does  match.
```

HTH!